# Add OwinStartup class in NET Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, owin, startup

I am building an ASP.NET Core WebApp (.Net Framework). [NET Core 1.1 / net462]

There's a standard Net Core Startup class with ConfigureService and Configure methods and the application builder interface is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder.

Now, i need to add an OwinStartup class where i basically map to the Owin.IAppBuilder interface in this way:

```
  app.Map("/ServiceHub", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

It is not clear to me how to run the owinstartup and net core startup class.
Or, in case i need to add an OwinMiddleware,  how i can configure it in order to map this configuration.